# Taking rows from dataframe until a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns:

```
      A B
    0 1 3
    1 2 2
    2 3 2
    3 9 3 
    4 1 1 
    ...
```

For a given index i, I want the rows from row i to the row j in which `df.at[j,A]-df.at[i,B]>5`. I don't want any rows after row j.

For example, let `i=1`, the output should be:

```
[out]
A B
2 2
3 2
9 3
```

Is there a simple way of do this without using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 1, 2, 3, 9], 'B': [1, 3, 2, 2, 3]})
i = 2
base = df.at[i, 'B']
df = df.iloc[i:]
j = df[df['A'] - df.at[i, 'B'] > 5]
if not j.empty:
    print(df.iloc[:j.index[0]])
else:
    print('Condition not found')
```

Prints:

```
   A  B
2  2  2
3  3  2
4  9  3
```

Comment: `df[df['A'] - base > 5].index[0]` will throw an error if `df[df['A'] - base > 5]` is an empty df. E.g. when we let `df.iloc[3].values` be `array([4, 3], dtype=int64)` rather than `array([9, 3], dtype=int64)`. In this case there is no index.

Answer (score 1):

You could try as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': {0: 10, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 9}, 'B': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

i=1
s = df.loc[i:,'A']-df.loc[i,'B']>5
trues = s[s==True]
if not trues.empty: 
    subset = df.iloc[i:trues.idxmax()+1]
else:
    subset = pd.DataFrame()
print(subset)

   A  B
1  2  2
2  3  2
3  9  3
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 1, 2, 3, 9], 'B': [1, 3, 2, 2, 3]})` with `i=2` will output the empty df

Comment: @АлексейР You are right. Using the new df, with i=1, it also gives empty df. Perhaps I'll use your df as the example as it is more general

Comment: @АлексейР: You're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it, I think.